# SSRS parameter pane layout changes when publishing report

Tags: layout, reporting-services, parameters

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2019 to build SSRS reports

I customize the parameters pane and it previews fine but for two reports but when one of them is published it changes

I have one report with the parameters panel customized, it has four columns and looks something like this

[Example of parameter pane layout for report that works when published](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyQLh.png)

When I publish the report the layout of the parameter panel stays the same

I have another report with a similar layout, which looks something like this

[Example of parameter pane layout for report that doesn't work when published](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCK4B.png)

When I preview the report locally the layout of the parameter panel stays the same:

However

When I publish the report it changes.

On the published report it looks like this

[Example of parameter pane layout on report that does not work when published](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfJpx.png)

The parameters are no longer flush with one another (there is space between them) and the number of characters in any line of the parameter description is reduced to that

[Example parameter Description1] [dropdown box] [Example parameter Description 2][dropdown box]

```
becomes

[Example                                  [Example
parameter       [dropdown box]             parameter [dropdown box]
Description 1]                             Description 2]
```

It takes up a lot of space and looks rather messy.

```
Server is
Windows Server 2019
With
SQL Server Developer
Product Version 15.0.1102.897

Local PC is
Windows 10 Pro
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Using Microsoft Edge both for the report that works (keeps same parameter pane layout when published) and the one that doesn't. Tried in Google Chrome and got the same results.

Comment: What version of SSRS is on the server that you are deploying to? Parameter layout ordering was introduced in 2012 (I think). It is not supported in 2008 but is definitely supported in 2016 onwards.

Comment: Hi Alan. It's 2019 (15.0.1102.897)... but as I said, it works fine for one report (retains the same layout of the parameter pane when the report is published) but not for another.